Error "Field doesn't have a default value" con postman y laravel
Tengo un proyecto con laravel con un modelo "esdeveniments" (1ra imagen, 2nda es la migracion), en caso de funcionar bien, simplemente me haria una insercion en la base de datos, pero me da el error.
Funcion para guardar en la base de datos
   public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $nouEsdeveniment = esdeveniments::create($request->all());
        return response()->json($nouEsdeveniment);
    }



Al intentar hacer un POST con Postman (3ra imagen), me da el error

Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'limit_entrades' doesn't have a default value (Connection: mysql, SQL: insert into esdeveniments (nom, data_esdeveniment, aforament, updated_at, created_at) values (Test2, 1, 20, 2024-04-02 07:49:35, 2024-04-02 07:49:35)) in file C:\laragon\www\Tokens\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php on line 822


Que es lo que estoy haciendo mal? No se si el error esta en la propia Request o en el codigo del proyecto.
El problema es que al hacer una peticion POST con el postman para inserir un objeto "esdeveniment" a la base de datos,  me da el error que puse en la pregunta. Entiendo que el error es que por algun motivo no coge los datos de "limit_entrades", pese a que los paso en la peticion, como se puede ver en la imagen.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

He hecho una edicion. Es suficiente?

Prueba hacer una validación del request antes de insertar en base de datos. Fíjate que en la query sql no está presente la columna. En postman prueba enviar como formulario o json en vez de query parámetros. Por cierto, el código va como texto, las imágenes de código no ayudan para leer tu pregunta

Enviandolo como JSON me funciono, muchas gracias. La proxima duda que envie sera con el codigo en texto.
